# Ambiguous use of 'filter' with nested filters

Tags: ios, swift, filter, realm, swift4

I'm doing some work on another developer's code. I had migrated it to Swift 4 successfully, but with the latest Swift upgrade (Swift 4.2?) I started getting `Ambigous use of 'filter'` errors. I was able to fix most of them by simply breaking complex statements down, but ran into one with nested filters that I'm not sure what to do with. Here's the complete function:

```
func validateSubmission(_ submissionId: Int) -> ([EntryModel]) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let submissionModel = realm.objects(SubmissionModel.self).filter({ $0.id == submissionId }).first!

    let entryModels = submissionModel.entryModels

    // Check for all entry details field which are mandatory and are empty and not hidden
    let emptyEntryModels = entryModels.filter({ $0.entryDetailArray.filter({ $0.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && $0.isMandatory && !($0.isHidden) }).count > 0 })

    return Array(emptyEntryModels)
}
```

I get the error on the line:

```
let emptyEntryModels = entryModels.filter({ $0.entryDetailArray.filter({ $0.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && $0.isMandatory && !($0.isHidden) }).count > 0 })
```

Can anyone tell me how to "rephrase" this into something more manageable, so I can eliminate the ambiguous filter issue?

Comment: Have you tried sth like: `return Array(submissionModel.entryModels).filter {
    $0.entryDetailArray.first { $0.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && $0.isMandatory && !$0.isHidden } != nil
}`

Comment: Please include your model class definitions in your question to make the issue reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Swift 4.0.3 and it didn't give me any error. Try it with type annotation maybe it will work

```swift
let emptyEntryModels: [EntryModel] = entryModels.filter({ $0.entryDetailArray.filter({ $0.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && $0.isMandatory && !($0.isHidden) }).count > 0 })

// if you want simplified version of it
var result: [EntryModel] = []
for entryModel in entryModels {
    for entryDetail in entryModel.entryDetailArray {
        if entryDetail.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && entryDetail.isMandatory && !entryDetail.isHidden {
            result.append(entryModel)
        }
    }
}
```